# CSS Background Image not working on Local

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for the basic question I have this problem when im trying to display my background image using background-image:url() on the css but unfortunately it doesnt work and when i use the content:url(); it works.

And also background-image also works with a url image location from the internet. I have tried everything and research a lot but still no luck. Sorry for the newbie question.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #e2dfe3;
    
}

.logo{
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('./images/Logo.png');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Practice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">


 <header>
<div class="logo">
</div>
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav-ul">
        <li> <a href="#">Homes</li>
        <li> <a href="#">About</li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</li>
    </ul>
    
    </nav>
    <a class="nav-button" href="#"></a><button>Login</button>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you show us your local file structure? just want to be sure your image file is reachable from where your index.html file lives

Comment: if the images folder is in the same directory try background-image: url('images/Logo.png');

Comment: @Richard Both my css and html are stored in **E:\Practice** while the image folder is in **E:\Practice\images**

Comment: @MoneerKamal I tried that also but it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the `<body>` tag.
(Its a good job you're not a mortician.)

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #e2dfe3;
    
}

.logo{
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Practice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-ul">
                <li> <a href="#">Homes</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="nav-button" href="#"><button>Login</button></a>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesnt work either. But if I use url image location from the internet like you use above the **background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/80x80/000/fff');** it works but when I call the image on my local  it doesnt work.

Comment: Check to ensure the relative path from your html file is correct. In the same folder as this html file you should have a folder called 'images' and inside that folder there should be a file called 'Logo.png'. 
How big is your image file? Try adding the following to the logo class:
```background-size: contain;```

Comment: It works now. I added `background-size: contain;` Thanks for the help. I Appreciate it a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

It works now. I added property background-size: contain;

```
.logo{
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('./images/Logo.png');
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: No problem. I suspected the image was larger than 80x80 and the top left square (80x80) were the same colour as the background so the image was rendering, you just couldnt see it because it wasnt scaling down to fit the height and width you'd specified. Background-size ensured it did that.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy your code and place in a file structure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7naMW.png)
And it works.

Absolute path like this also worked well:

```
background-image: url('C:/Users/User/Documents/test/images/logo.png');
```